# Moving TFS 2017 from HTTP to HTTPS causes extensions not working properly

Tags: tfs

I installed TFS 2017 to be accessible on both, HTTP (port 8080, default settings) and HTTPS. Now I removed HTTP binding form the IIS and reapplied the Public URL (via Administration Console -> Change Public URL).

Most of the TFS application tier works normally (as it uses relative addressing). However, build extensions somehow want to get their icons from HTTP (port 8080). See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qvqd.png). When I noticed this, I first checked the HTML/JS source and I found that `_vssPageContext` variable still holds some URLs pointing to old HTTP configuration.

Has anyone solved that mistery or has any idea what to do?

EDIT: Later I re-enabled the HTTP bindings in IIS just to make the TFS work and I get a lot of warnings and errors due to HTTP / HTTPS mixup (I access TFS via HTTPS, however some content is still accessed via HTTP):

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx/tfs/TFSDefault/Project/_build/definitionEditor?definitionId=113&_a=simple-process'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx:8080/tfs/TFSDefault/_apis/distributedtask/tasks/9fcb05af-0ffe-4687-99f2-99821aad927e/0.1.1305/icon'.
>   This content should also be served over HTTPS.
>
> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx:8080/tfs/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&contextToken=412c3608-de3b-4dab-a00d-bf5c13728d97&connectionToken=OoSymcl1qzWg%2BrHB9pzSBpb%2BdHVywo7NNUWN5xMx3Z51p9ZdZQ14wvoQKXqxB%2Bvo66eTap4iUdlqzHR1hJNUf%2By8oFUaudlkCbQIZjHQhLBHsEWtcLdfLlL7MAevl4h0My1yQA%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22builddetailhub%22%7D%5D&tid=7'
>   failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available.

Comment: Did you recycle the application pool?

Comment: Yes. I also rebooted the server. Without success.

Comment: Worst case solution, I configure the app tier and reconfigure it with the ssl binding right from the installer. Or send a feedback request to the new visual Studio feedback site.

Comment: Try with different browser? "WebSocket connection to..... HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available." is very familiar with Chrome

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to the default endpoint of TFS being initially set as http, which all the elements are then defaulting their requests to, rather than relying on the initial request you are making in the browser. so you end up with a javascript element attempting to connect to the server via http and get a cross content issue.

Here is a really good article that covers the issues you are probably facing and how to fix them to use https: https://hybriddbablog.com/2017/12/16/changing-tfs-to-use-https-update-your-agent-settings-too/

I have to caveat that I havent done this yet, we actually went back in favour of running http until we moved to the next version of TFS, but from my experience of TFS, the steps look sound.